# Javascript .change(function() calculate age based on date

Tags: javascript, html

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#dob').change(function()
        {
            var dob = new Date(document.getElementById('dob').value);
            var today = new Date();
            var age = Math.floor((today-dob)/(365.25*24*60*60*1000));
            document.getElementById('age').value = age;
        });
    });
</script>
```

```
<div class="input-field col  s12">
   <label for="dob_label">Date of Birth</label></br>
   <input type="date" name="dob" id="dob" required/>
</div>

<div class="input-field col  s12">
   <label for="age_label">age</label></br>
   <input type="text" name="age" id="age" readonly/>
</div>
```

This is what I've tried for auto calculation of age in javaScript but seems that the input age is not responsive when I've pick a date on the dob input. Please let me know which part that I've missed out for this function.

Comment: What is your query actually? I checked your code and its working and calculating age dynamically.

Comment: Ya,I am not sure about it, because I think that my code should work. After selecting the dob the age input is not responding at all

Comment: Your code is working fine to me

Comment: I've tried with alert('age'); but still not responding

Comment: @gammer With the change event you have to lose the focus to trigger the event. Thus, you have to insert and lose the focus on the input element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check in the Run Code Snippet - Your code is working

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title></title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#dob').change(function()
        {
            console.log("change");
            var dob = new Date(document.getElementById('dob').value);
            var today = new Date();
            var age = Math.floor((today-dob)/(365.25*24*60*60*1000));
            document.getElementById('age').value = age;
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="input-field col  s12">
   <label for="dob_label">Date of Birth</label></br>
   <input type="date" name="dob" id="dob" required/>
</div>

<div class="input-field col  s12">
   <label for="age_label">age</label></br>
   <input type="text" name="age" id="age" readonly/>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works now, thanks for the help. I've missed out the ```<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>```

Comment: Oh small beginner mistake..next time keep in mind of using cdns. All the best and keep coding.